# How do i normalise this database?

Tags: database, normalization

I am learning database design and having a problem grasping the different steps of normalisation. I can do simple ones mainly but this problem I am trying to solve is making me hit a brickwall.

I am creating a database which records jobs created by a user who is initiating a transfer of files from one ftp host to another. Each ftp host can have multiple folders available to be shared.
These are my attributes I have come up with -

- Job ID
- Date Created
- Source Host ID
- Source Folder ID
- Destination Host ID
- Destination Folder ID
- Frequency
- Start Date
- Finish Date
- Status
- Comments
- User ID
- First Name
- Last Name
- Password
- User Access Level
- FTP Host ID
- Location Name
- Status
- Folder ID
- Folder Location
- Folder Access Level
- File ID
- File Name
- File Size
- File Date Created
- File Date Modified

I know I will at least have a Job, FTP host, Folders, Files and Users tables. But I cannot seem to work out how to normalise it, due to having the source and destination host ID/folders being the same as a host ID/folders. Could anyone show me it in 1NF/2NF/3NF? Would appreciate it!

Comment: side-note: never store passwords in plaintext in your database.

Comment: Note that we cannot normalize the proposed structure for you because you've not stipulated any functional dependencies for the attributes.  Without that key information (pun intended), there's nothing that can be done.